# How to search and trim image filenames from json using regex?

Tags: objective-c, regex, nsregularexpression

I need to trim image filenames inside json to empty values, so I'v started to try with regex. There are different image tags in json but they all end with "_url" suffix. Tried various combinations with regex but with no luck. How such regex could look like?

Here's what I have:

```
{ "list" : 
  [
    {
        "id" : 123,
        "name" : "some name",
        "description" : "Lorem ipsum",
        "logo_image_url": "222.png",
        "content_image_url" : "1355.png"},

    {   
        "id" : 123,
        "name" : "some other name",
        "description" : "Lorem ipsum",
        "logo_image_url": "111.png",
        "content_image_url" : "1355.png"
    }
  ]
}
```

And this is what I need to make:

```
{ "list" : 
  [
    {
        "id" : 123,
        "name" : "some name",
        "description" : "Lorem ipsum",
        "logo_image_url": "",
        "content_image_url" : ""},

    {   
        "id" : 123,
        "name" : "some other name",
        "description" : "Lorem ipsum",
        "logo_image_url": "",
        "content_image_url" : ""
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: `Tried various combinations with regex but with no luck` Please post what you have tried, otherwise you just seem like a helpvampire. On another note, editing JSON with regex is generally a **big NO**. I suggest to use a proper JSON parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This id doable with an expression like this:

`("(?:logo_image_url|content_image_url)"\s*:\s*)".*?"`, replace with `\1""`

Though as pointed out by @HamZa: editing JSON with regex is generally a big no-no.

Demo+explanation: http://regex101.com/r/oY3mJ9